# Quick search box for Contacts in Android

Tags: android, contacts, quick-search

I want to create a quick search box to search contacts. when a word is typed in search box then it gives list of contacts which are matches with that word.

Comment: You could accomplish that with using the SearchView in ActionBar and requesting the contacts from the Contacts Provider.